# managing a HTML list in flask python

Tags: python, html, flask

I had this piece of code written in HTML.

```
<nav id="mainnav">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected-item"><a href="proceed.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="caesarcipher.html">Caesar Cipher</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

It was working fine and on clicking the item, the respective link/page was working. But when I now opened this page in flask python, I could not open the links describe here in the HTML code. It throws a error saying "Not Found".

Kindly help me with this code or guide me to any source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use route in views.py:

```
@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')
```

And url_for in HTML template:

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
```

Where 'contact' is name function. Or just:

```
<li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```